# Reading Excel(xlsx) with Pyspark does not work above a certain medium size

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Having the following configuration of a cluster in databricks: `64GB, 8 cores`

The tests have been carried out as the only notebook in the cluster, at that time there were no other notebooks running.
I find that reading a simple 30 MB Excel file in spark keeps loading and does not work. Using the following code for this purpose:

```
sdf = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\
                .option("header", True)\
                .option("inferSchema", "true")\
                .load(my_path)
display(sdf)
```

I have tried reducing the excel file and it works fine up to 15MB.
As a workaround I am going to export the excel to csv and read it from there, but I find it shocking that spark can't even read 30MB of excel.

or am I doing something wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the below option as shown in this [spark-excel - github](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel#create-a-dataframe-from-an-excel-file) ?

Based on your input you can modify the number of rows. The value 20 is an sample value.

`.option("maxRowsInMemory", 20) // Optional, default None. If set, uses a streaming reader which can help with big files (will fail if used with xls format files)`

As mentioned above, the option does not work for .xls files.

In case the files are really big, consider the options as show in the link [#590](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/issues/590)

Please validate before using any of the options specified.

Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

You need to install these 2 libraries on your databricks cluster to read excel files. Follow these paths to install:

`Clusters -> select your cluster -> Libraries -> Install New -> Maven -> in Coordinates: com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.5`

`Clusters -> select your cluster -> Libraries -> Install New -> PyPI-> in Package: xlrd`

Now, you will be able to read your excel as follows:

```
sdf = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("dataAddress", "'NameOfYourExcelSheet'!A1") \
    .load(filePath)
```

Comment: could you explain why adding these 2 libraries will improve the process ? right now work read excel when are small files

Comment: Have you tried it?